# Use a third column of values to map a color gradient to a plot of column 1 and column 2; Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, colormap

I have a dataframe with 3 columns. I'm using df['name'] as x-axis and df['value1'] as y-axis. I would like to use the 3rd column (df['value2']) to produce a color gradient for a barplot.

**Data in Use**

df['name'] are names. df['value1'] are primary measurements. df['value2'] are confidence metrics for the values of df['value1']. I think displaying df['value2'] in color gradient would produce a powerful visual.

**Issues**

I have attempted a myriad of ways of achieving this with matplotlib.colors modules but nothing has produced the result I'm looking for. Here is the base of the code (no color mapping to df['value2']).

**INPUT**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap
import matplotlib.colors as colors


df = {'name': ['a','b','c','d'], 'value1': [10.1,13.3,9.5,15.1], 'value2': [1.5,2.0,3.5,1.3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(df)


colorbar_1 = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('colorbar', ['#990000','#FF6666'], N=100)
df[['name','value1']].plot(kind='bar', colormap=colorbar_1 ,width=0.8, ylim=[9,16], fontsize=5)
plt.xticks(df.index,df['name'].values, rotation=90)
plt.ylim([9,16])
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('test.png',dpi=600)
plt.show()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
  name  value1  value2
0    a    10.1     1.5
1    b    13.3     2.0
2    c     9.5     3.5
3    d    15.1     1.3
```

Result:
[image: 'test.png']

**Desired Format**

[[image: 'Desired-format']

I have also produced a 4th column with generated hex code that could be used to perform the task at hand. I assume there are easier methods of incorporating df['value2'] but having generated hex code may be handy?

**INPUT**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap
import matplotlib.colors as colors

df = {'name': ['a','b','c','d'], 'value1': [10.1,13.3,9.5,15.1], 'value2': [1.5,2.0,3.5,1.3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(df)

norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=16, clip=True)
mapper = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=plt.cm.viridis)
df['hex_code'] = df['value2'].apply(lambda x: colors.to_hex(mapper.to_rgba(x)))
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
  name  value1  value2
0    a    10.1     1.5
1    b    13.3     2.0
2    c     9.5     3.5
3    d    15.1     1.3
  name  value1  value2 hex_code
0    a    10.1     1.5  #482374
1    b    13.3     2.0  #472d7b
2    c     9.5     3.5  #3e4989
3    d    15.1     1.3  #481d6f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems is that using `df[['name', 'value1']].plot` makes pandas think you want two bars per row in the dataframe, one bar for 'name' and one for 'value1'. And then pandas gets confused as it can not draw a bar for 'name' and skips these. Then, for the `color=` parameter, pandas now thinks the first color in the color list is for 'name' and the second is for 'value1'.

So, to start, you need to call it as `df['value1'].plot()`. Then, pandas really likes to use the index for the x-axis. To have the 'name' as the index, just make it the index of your dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap, Normalize

df = {'name': ['a','b','c','d'], 'value1': [10.1,13.3,9.5,15.1], 'value2': [1.5,2.0,3.5,1.3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df.set_index('name', inplace=True)
print(df)

colormap_1 = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('colorbar', ['#990000','#FF6666'], N=100)
norm = Normalize(vmin=min(df['value2']), vmax=max(df['value2']))
colors = [colormap_1(norm(v)) for v in df['value2']]
df['value1'].plot(kind='bar', color=colors, width=0.8, ylim=[9,16], fontsize=5)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.ylim([9,16])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('test.png',dpi=600)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: To get something similar to your linked image (thus not using 'value2'), you could experiment with:

```py
# same dataframe as before, with 'name' as index
ymin = 9
ymax = 16
barplot = df['value1'].plot(kind='bar', width=0.8, ylim=[ymin, ymax], fontsize=5)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

gradient = np.linspace(1,0,256).reshape(256,1)
for bar in barplot.containers[0]:
    bar.set_facecolor("none")
    x, y = bar.get_xy()
    w, h = bar.get_width(), bar.get_height()
    plt.imshow(gradient, extent=[x, x + w, y + ymin, y + h], aspect="auto", cmap='bone')
plt.imshow(gradient, extent=[*plt.xlim(), *plt.ylim()] ,aspect="auto", cmap='copper_r', zorder=-1)

plt.tight_layout()
#plt.savefig('test.png',dpi=600)
plt.show()
```